# How to ensure that if dropdown selection is first item nothing happens

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the code below to open a pop up when user makes a selection. What I would like is to block when user selects the first item in the drop down as it has no real value. Also, I want to allow user to reselect already selected option by clicking the dropdownlist option again.

```
function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
           var inputFieldValue;
           var item = eventArgs.get_item();
           grid = $find("<%= rggrid.ClientID %>");

           var selectedRows = grid.get_selectedItems();
           if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
               for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                   var row = selectedRows[i];
                   inputField = MasterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "Item")
                   if (inputField) {
                       inputFieldValue = inputField.value
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
           else {
               var inputFieldID = window['textItembox'];
               inputField = document.getElementById(inputFieldID);
               if (inputField) {
                    inputFieldValue = inputField.value;
                   }
           }
           window.radopen('<%=linker %> , "UserDialog");
           return false;
       }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing ajax here, or jquery ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When is the OnClientSelectedIndexChanged fired??

Anyway here is a quick sample:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Select" onclick="Button1_Click" />

$('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                if ($('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>').val() == "-1")
                    return false;
                alert($('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>').val());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
onclick = return(false);
```

to diable action on the first block and

```
mousedown = function(e){e.target.checked;}
```

or

```
mousedown = function(e){e.target.parentNode.selectedIndex = e.target.index;}
```

to be able to select your selected option again